# Update with Subquery never completes

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, subquery

I'm currently working on a project with a MySQL Db of more than 8 million rows. I have been provided with a part of it to test some queries on it. It has around 20 columns out of which 5 are of use to me. Namely: `First_Name, Last_Name, Address_Line1, Address_Line2, Address_Line3, RefundID`

I have to create a unique but random `RefundID` for each row, that is not the problem. The problem is to create **same** `RefundID` for those rows whose `First_Name, Last_Name, Address_Line1, Address_Line2, Address_Line3` as same.

This is my first real work related to MySQL with such large row count. So far I have created these queries:

```
-- Creating Teporary Table --
CREATE temporary table tempT (SELECT tt.First_Name, count(tt.Address_Line1) as
a1, count(tt.Address_Line2) as a2, count(tt.Address_Line3) as a3, tt.RefundID
FROM `tempTable` tt GROUP BY First_Name HAVING a1 >= 2 AND a2 >= 2 AND a3 >= 2);
-- Updating Rows with First_Name from tempT --
UPDATE `tempTable` SET RefundID = FLOOR(RAND()*POW(10,11))
WHERE First_Name IN (SELECT First_Name FROM tempT WHERE First_Name is not NULL);
```

This update query keeps on running but never ends, `tempT` has more than 30K rows. This query will then be run on the main DB with more than 800K rows.

Can someone help me out with this?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions that seem obvious to me....

Don't use a random value - use a hash:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET refundid = MD5('some static salt', First_Name
   , Last_Name, Address_Line1, Address_Line2, Address_Line3)
```

The problem is that if you are using an integer value for the refundId then there's a good chance of getting a collision (hint CONV(SUBSTR(MD5(...),1,16),16,10) to get a SIGNED BIGINT). But you didn't say what the type of the field was, nor how strict the 'unique' requirement was. It does carry out the update in a single pass though.

An alternate approach which creates a densely packed seguence of numbers is to create a temporary table with the unique values from the original table and a random value. Order by the random value and set a monotonically increasing refundId - then use this as a look up table or update the original table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT First_Name
   , Last_Name, Address_Line1, Address_Line2, Address_Line3
INTO temptable
FROM yourtable;

set @counter=-1;

UPDATE temptable t SET t,refundId=(@counter:=@counter + 1)
ORDER BY r.randomvalue;
```

There are other solutions too - but the more efficient ones rely on having multiple copies of the data and/or using a procedural language.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply, RefundID has to be unique values of 9-12 digits. MD5 is of 32 digits i think (bad numeric memory). I have to give same ID to every row where `First_Name, Last_Name, Address_Line1, Address_Line2, Address_Line3` are same. Regards

Comment: Yes, I suspected that might be the case and did explicitly address this in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
UPDATE `tempTable` x  SET RefundID = FLOOR(RAND()*POW(10,11))
WHERE exists  (SELECT 1  FROM tempT y WHERE First_Name is not NULL and x.First_Name=y.First_Name);
```

Comment: I'm running your query at the moment, how long would you think this would take on a i7 with 4GB Ram? My PC specs. I.E for around 30K rows.

Comment: I wouldn't venture a guess, although if it were me, I'd try it with 100 results, then 1000, then 10000, etc to see if it starts breaking down.. also you could use explain to gather what it's doing that's taking so long. The exists version should be faster though.

Comment: I let it run for 6 minutes and it never ended, I'll try it first with 10 rows. Thanks

Comment: Well, its not even completing for a single row.I want to match it by `First_Name` in the `tempT` and the same column name in `tempTable`.

Comment: Can you set up a test schema in sqlfiddle.com, so I can play with it?
Also, are you within a transaction?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, it is often more efficient to use `join` with `update` than to filter through the `where` clause using a subquery.  The following might perform better:

```
UPDATE `tempTable` join
       (SELECT distinct First_Name
        FROM tempT
        WHERE First_Name is not NULL
       ) fn
       on temptable.First_Name = fn.First_Name
    SET RefundID = FLOOR(RAND()*POW(10,11));
```